# Odd JQuery $.post behavior

Tags: jquery, post, .post

I'm learning $.post in jquery, and after many hours I was thrilled that it worked.

The problem is that it only works on the first execution of the page, or if I manually refresh the page.

Is it possible that location.reload(); isn't working properly or perhaps location.reload() isn't the right thing here?

Any help appreciated. I'm dead stuck.

Here's my code:

```
<script type="application/x-javascript">

    $("a#edit").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var id;
        id = $(this).attr('sid');
        $.modal.prompt('Editing Source ID: ' + id,
            function(){
                $.post("<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>", { 
                                        up: $('#prompt-value').attr('value'),
                                        sid: id                                         
                                        })
                notify('Notification', 'Source ' + id + ' changed to: ' + $('#prompt-value').attr('value'), {
                    system: true,
                    icon: 'img/demo/icon.png',
                    iconOutside: false
                });
                location.reload();
             });
    });

</script>
```

I'm at a total loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a console.log($("a#edit")) before you attach the click event.

This code is confusing since you appear to be AJAX posting to the current file, then refreshing, kind of makes the ajax post useless, might as well have posted to itself.

Most jquery functions are async, use the success callback or deferred done if the notification should only be executed on success.

```
$.post("<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>", 
    { 
        up: $('#prompt-value').attr('value'),
        sid: id                                         
    }        
).done(function (data) {
    // Success, read response data, send notification if applicable and use 
    // the response data to change the current page without having to refresh
}).fail(function () {
    // Failure on the request, handle it
});
```

Comment: That worked, but I still needed to do the location.reload(). This is due to the table I'm editing being called from a PHP function at the beginning of the document. When the page loads it executes a php function to fetchAllUsers and then in the body I use HTML and PHP to build the table of users. This click action is on the edit button in the row with the users (attrib'd by ID).

I couldn't think of any way to refresh that php funnction to fetchAllUsers and re-write the table without reloading the page. And the thought of executing php in javascript makes me ill.

Comment: If this is working it is working. But consider reading about MVC to help you organize your code in the future, by your description i'm assuming that code is not easy to read or maintain :)

Comment: Have any suggestions? I'm taking your advice and I'm reading about cakePHP and CodeIgniter now. Not sure which will be easiest to pick up and use with JqueryUI.

Comment: PHP code should never limit your ability to develop good interfaces. You can use jQueryUI (or any other javascript client side library) with any of those frameworks. MVC just makes sure u separate what is persistent in your app (model), what is logic (controller), and what is interface (view), the end result is usually a lot easier to read and maintain. From my experience CakePHP is the easiest to learn, but not exactly the most efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 $("a#edit").live('click',function(e){
 ...
 });
```

jQuery 1.4.+ i think

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/live/
whats the down vote for , did you even tried it or the alternatives?
As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

Comment: The page is reloading after the prompt, I don't think this is a delegation problem. Not to mention, `.live` doesn't exist in the current version of jQuery.

Comment: He isn't bringing any new content into his page for a delegated event to target.

Comment: Downvote wasn't me - I just came back to check. I'm trying both of the suggestions now.